# Did I evaluate the improper integral $\int_1^2 {1 \over (1-x)^2}dx$ correctly?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_1^2 {1 \over (1-x)^2}dx$$
$$u = 1 - x$$
$$-du = dx$$

$$\lim_{a \to 0^-}-\int_0^{-1} {du \over u^2} = \lim_{a \to 0^-}\int_{-1}^{a} {du \over u^2}$$

$$\lim_{a \to 0^-} {1 \over u}|_{-1}^a $$
$$\lim_{a \to 0^-} {1 \over a} - {1 \over -1} = \infty + 1 = \infty \ = D.N.E. $$

Comment: Did you mean "$a$ tends to $1$ by the right side"?

Comment: Also after the substitution you have to change the limits of integration.

Comment: why do you have $\infty?$ the $u$ limits $0$ to $1.$. the singularity at $x = 1$ is not iintegrable.

Comment: You have not used that $\mathbb{d}x=-\mathbb{d}u$. The primitive of $\frac 1 {u^2}$ is $- \frac 1 u$.

Comment: That is not correct, as pointed out in the previous comments you are taking the limit to $\infty$, when it should be to $1^+$, also you are not making the limits of integration after the $u$ substitution and finally the integral **does not converge**

Comment: @Alonso Delfín So I have to change the bounds after I make it 'u'?

Comment: @Jay Yes. You should do that and all of the other errors that were pointed out.

Comment: Alright I'm on it

Comment: Yes, if $u=1-x$, then when $x=1$ you have $u=0$ and if $x=2$ then $u=-1$. Note that $\int_0^{-1}=-\int_{-1}^0$, and take the limit $a\to 0^-$ since the singularity is now on $u=0$

Comment: @user222031 I made some changes, how does that look now?

Comment: It looks ok but $$\int \frac{du}{u^2} = -\frac{1}{u} + C$$

Comment: @user222031 Yep you're right I keep forgetting about the negative